# How Randall-Sundrum model has solved the hierarchy problem?

Tags: general-relativity, string-theory, standard-model, supersymmetry, spacetime-dimensions

I'm trying to understand how the RS model solved the hierarchy problem from this mass relation

$$ M^2_p = \frac{M^3}{k} \Large[1- e^{-2k\pi r} \Large],$$

Equ. 16 in their paper:

https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221

With k as large as the Planck scale, the exponential will be so small and almost has no effect, which leads to (is this correct? ), as they say in page 6, $M \approx M_p$!

So the conflict rises here, cause $M_p$ is the four dimensional effective Planck scale $\sim 10^{18}$ GeV, while $M$ is the higher 5-dimensional Planck scale assumed to be at TeV scale, so what does $M \approx M_p$ mean?

Any help is appreciated!

See also the discussion in this thread:
[The hierarchy problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/661737/the-hierarchy-problem?noredirect=1#comment1484638_661737)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M$ is indeed approximately equal to the 4-d Planck scale $M_{\rm pl}$. The hierarchy problem is why the Higgs mass $m_H$ is so much smaller than the Planck scale. In the original version of the Randall-Sundrum model, this happens because the standard model fields live on a brane inside a warped throat. The warping factor leads to an exponential suppression of all particle masses relative to the Planck scale. See Eq. 21 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9905221

\begin{equation}
m = e^{-k r_c \pi}m_0
\end{equation}
where $m_0 \sim M$ and $e^{-k r_c \pi}$ is a *warping factor* that accounts for the warped geometry of the extra dimension.

In slightly more detail, the metric is (Eq 12)
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = e^{-2 k r_c |\phi|} \eta_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + r_c^2 d\phi^2
\end{equation}
where $-\pi \leq \phi \leq \pi$. The standard model lives on a brane at $\phi=\pi$ (see Eq 3), where leading to coefficient of the Minkowski metric above to be $e^{-2 k r_c \pi}$, which leads to the exponential suppression of the particle masses after computing the effective four dimensional theory on the brane.

Comment: Thanks that is so helpful, I got it, so they assume even the fifth extra dimension have a large Planck scale as well, but in the same time their model predicts the right masses of the SM particles. This is so different mechanism than the so called ADD model ( Arkani-Hamed-Dimopoulos-Dvali) which is known by assuming large extra dimensions to make M of order TeV

Comment: The RS model seems a successful scenario, even I have found articles on how people try to find its graviton excitations at the LHC. However don't you think assuming a static 3-brane where the SM particles live doesn't apply on our universe? @Andrew. I can't find in the metric, Eq. 2, any time dependence for the wrap factor

Comment: @Dr.phy (a) Correct, there is no time dependence in the warp factor. (b) It's a plausible model, but hasn't led to any predictions confirmed by experiment.